# Set width of SidebarView in macOS using SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm using a NavigationView to display a SidebarView and DetailView in the window of a Mac app:

```swift
import SwiftUI

private let fruits = [" Apple", " Coconut", " Mango", " Kiwi"]

struct SidebarView: View {

    @Binding var selectedFruit: String?

    var body: some View {
        List(fruits, id: \.self, selection: $selectedFruit) { fruit in
            Text("\(fruit)")
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .frame(minWidth: 180, idealWidth: 200, maxWidth: 300)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {

    @Binding var fruit: String?

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(fruit ?? "Default Fruit")")
            .font(.headline)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selectedFruit: String?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            SidebarView(selectedFruit: $selectedFruit)
            DetailView(fruit: $selectedFruit)
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 400)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The width of the SidebarView can be adjusted by dragging the center divider left or right in the window. I would like to have an initial width of 200 defined for the sidebar along with a minimum width of 180 and a max width of 300. I attempted this by setting the frame of the List which does indeed set the max width but the sidebar can still be completely collapsed. Also, the initial width of the sidebar seems to be defined by `minWidth` not `idealWidth`.

Comment: Did you sort this? I find there is some automatic SceneStorage between runs/builds, so it's hard to tell exactly what every change will do for a fresh user. Unlike you, I cannot set a maxWidth for the sidebar, instead maxWidth only forces the sidebar contents to center themselves as the sidebar expands. I must set .maxWidth at infinity. Similarly, the minWidth only sets the "compression point" before hiding the sidebar. Using .layoutPriority(1) or .fixedSize(...) doesn't help. It's all rather unexpected. Even the SidebarCommands() commands don't appear as expected.

Comment: @Beginner I think the next version of SwiftUI has fixed this issue. But I'm waiting for it to come out of beta before confirming the fix.

Comment: Sadly I'm using the Beta...

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this?  I can't set a maxWidth for my sidebar either

Comment: The code you have here SHOULD work. SidebarView should not be allowed to grow more than 300. But alas it fails. I have a similar issue (macOS) and attempts to figure out why or how to fix are all failing :-(

Answer (score 11):

For anyone who finds this and is wanting to know how to set the maxWidth of a sidebar in macOS, you really don't. If you do, the view will stop growing and then be caught in the middle of the sidebar, which will keep expanding.

It took me a minute to figure this out, but what you do is set the minWidth of the other view, the detail view. And the sidebar will grow until it can't. You'll notice that even the sidebar of Finder grows and grows until it hits the minWidth of the detail, so to speak.

Comment: Can you provide some example code for this answer?

Comment: Actually, this is the correct answer.

Comment: Oh this is funny ... But it makes absolutely no sense to me. I don't want to constrain the detail. The detail should take all available.width - sidebar.width. I want to constrain the SideBar from growing crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Having been inspired by the answer from MScottWaller, I just added some calculations to the min size for the detailview.
This seems to pin the SideBar to between 220 and 380
Works on macOS 126.1/Xcode 14.0.1

The critical piece is the **private func minDetailWidth()**

```
    struct ItemListView: View {
        struct ItemRow: View {
            struct ItemView: View {
                let item: Item

                var body: some View {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: item.imageName)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                            .padding(2)
                            .overlay(Circle().strokeBorder(Color.black.opacity(0.1)))
                            .shadow(radius: 3)
                            .padding(4)

                        Text(item.name)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                }
            }

            let item: Item

            var body: some View {
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemView(item: item)) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: item.imageName)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2))
                            .padding(2)
                            .overlay(Circle().strokeBorder(Color.black.opacity(0.1)))
                            .shadow(radius: 3)
                            .padding(4)

                        Text(item.name)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        let items: [Item]

        var body: some View {
            List(items) { fruit in
                ItemRow(item: fruit)
            }
        }
    }

    struct Item: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let name: String
        let imageName: String
        let color: Color
    }

    class Model: ObservableObject {
        @Published var transportation: [Item] = loadTransportation()
        @Published var vegetables: [Item] = loadVegetables()

        static func loadTransportation() -> [Item] {
            return [
                Item(name: "Airplane", imageName: "airplane", color: .orange),
                Item(name: "Car", imageName: "car", color: .blue),
                Item(name: "Bus", imageName: "bus.fill", color: .red),
                Item(name: "Tram", imageName: "tram.fill", color: .pink),
                Item(name: "Ferry", imageName: "ferry", color: .purple),
                Item(name: "Bicycle", imageName: "bicycle", color: .green),
            ]
        }

        static func loadVegetables() -> [Item] {
            return [
                Item(name: "Spinach", imageName: "spinach", color: .red),
                Item(name: "Lettuce", imageName: "lettuce", color: .orange),
                Item(name: "Tomatoes", imageName: "tomatoes", color: .green),
                Item(name: "Onion", imageName: "onion", color: .blue),
            ]
        }
    }

    @ObservedObject private var model = Model()
    private var sideBarMaxWidth = 380.0

    /**
     window width minus the sideBarMaxWidth
     */
    private func minDetailWidth(_ proxy: GeometryProxy) -> Double {
        let rv_ = proxy.size.width - sideBarMaxWidth
        let rv = max(rv_, 480)
        // Log4swift[Self.self].info("\(rv)")
        return rv
    }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    NavigationLink(
                        "Fruits",
                        destination:
                            ItemListView(items: self.model.transportation)
                            .frame(minWidth: minDetailWidth(proxy), idealWidth: 840, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    )

                    NavigationLink(
                        "Vegetables",
                        destination:
                            ItemListView(items: self.model.vegetables)
                            .frame(minWidth: minDetailWidth(proxy), idealWidth: 840, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    )
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 220, maxWidth: sideBarMaxWidth)

                Text("Nothing Selected")
                    .frame(minWidth: minDetailWidth(proxy), maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleView()
        // .background(Color(NSColor.windowBackgroundColor))
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)

        ExampleView()
        // .background(Color(NSColor.windowBackgroundColor))
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can set the `minWidth` for `DetailView`. I tried it works well.

Comment: Please share the code as part of your answer.

Comment: Please add a brief code example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).